# Intellij perforce plugin issue - com/intellij/openapi/vcs/FileRenameProvider [Plugin: Perforce]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, perforce

I tried using Perforce plugin in intellij. After i restarted the intellij, it doesn't open and throws the below exception

```
Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: com/intellij/openapi/vcs/FileRenameProvider [Plugin: Perforce]
```

could some one help in fixing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall? JetBrains who makes the plugin showed a similar error where workaround was to disable git4idea before running inspections https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132298

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete "C:\Users\.IntelliJI\config\plugins" this path.
Hope to help you!

Comment: C:\Users\username\.IntelliJI_Name\config\plugins